# Android apk installation error after compiling the edited apk

Tags: android, testing, certificate, apk, ddms

For testing purpose, I decompiled an apk with apktool, modified the android manifest file (just set android:debuggable=true). I then decompiled it and signed it. I am getting the following error while installing it on my phone:

```
package com.test.test has no certificates at entry AndroidManifest.xml. ignoring
```

Why am I seeing this error, I signed it. If I do not change the manifest file it works after decompiling and compiling. I guess android stores separate certificate or sha1 values for each file. So the previous and current files are not matching. How can I solve this?

Comment: Everytime I try to decompile an apk and recompile it it only makes it all messed up

Comment: Hi i want to get method coverage for third party apps. I am doing research on android testing. For that I need to set the android:debuggable to true. If i can bypass that and debug the app, i do not need to decompile.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, Actually it was not adding the sha1 entries for the androidmanifest.xml file in the manifest.MF file. I was using android apk multitool and used the wrong command. Now it is working.